# MAUI: Shell returning to a previous page rather than intended page

Tags: .net, maui

I have a sample Maui Shell app with Flyout to demonstrate a page flow issue I have been experiencing, not sure if this is a misunderstanding on my part or a bug in Maui.

Sample app: https://github.com/d-harding/maui-pageflow

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run app on Android (or iOS)
2. Click `Go to Page 1`
3. Click `Go to Page 2`
4. Click `Go to SubMainPage`
5. Open Flyout and click `Return to MainPage`

When `Return to MainPage` is clicked, the command is executing the following `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(MainPage)}/");` (as well as `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");`). This should return the user directly to the page based on the URL, however, `OnAppearing` will be triggered for `Page2`, which is unwanted and not desired.

Routes for `MainPage` and `SubMainPage` are defined in `AppShell.xaml`, where `Page1` and `Page2` are using `RegisterRoute` in `AppShell.xaml.cs` as to only show Back button.

In short, I would like the `GoToAsync` mentioned above, to navigate the user directly "back" to the `Mainpage` regardless of the route (page flow) the user took to get there.

Edit (Jan 26th):

I've created and issue in the Github for Maui: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20141

Unfortunately it has been added to the backlog at this time.

Comment: Absolute route is two slashes. As per documentation `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//animals/monkeys");`. So you need to reduce your leading slashes to two slashes and you need to remove the trailing slash. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't resolve the issue in my sample, changing to `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");` still yields the same result, Page2's `OnAppearing()` still gets triggered with the above call.  Sample updated as well.

Comment: @Derek I can reproduce this potential issue on my side  and looks like the `OnAppearing()` is not running at the correct times. Since you have reported on Github, you can follow up there:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20141